# How to count the number of commas of each row in csv using powershell?

Tags: csv, powershell

How do I count the number of commas of each row in a csv file using powershell ?
The purpose of this is to compare with the number of commas in the header row. If it is not the same, then display the row number. I have tried to search online but couldn't find a solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this. However, if you have quoted values with commas inside, you need to write a regex to either do the count or at least remove the false-positives.

I'm using the header (line1) as a baseline for how many commas there should be.

```
###########SAMPLE####
$data = @"
header1,header2,header3
value1,value2,value3
value1,value2,,value3
value1,,value2,value3
value1,value2,value3
"@ -split "`n"
######################

$data = Get-Content myfile.csv

#Count in header
$header = $data[0].Split(",").Count
#Line counter
$i = 1

#Find lines with less or more commas
$data | ForEach-Object { 
    $c = $_.Split(",").Count
    if($c -ne $header) { "Line $i - $c commas" }
    $i++
}
```